# Removing blank spaces on window.print()

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove blank spaces which showing only on window.print();

[image: here]

Blank spaces are inputs hidden with css class like this:

```
@media screen {
    .hide-from-screen {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    .hide-from-printer {
        display: none;
    }  
}
```

So they are hidden which is good, but instead of hidding blank spaces are added. 
Is there some solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your css and some HTML and it works fine.
You should hide with `class="hide-from-printer"` every `<div>` which is not need to show.

If you want to show some `<div>` use CSS bellow:

```
@media print {
    #printOnly {
       display : block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height for the same and !important

```
@media print {
    .hide-from-printer {
        display: none !important;
        height: 0px;
    }  
}
```